# How to send user_data with gtk signals in loop

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I have signals "make" and "send" registered in core class in main thread. I call `call_make()` from user class in same thread. `call_make()` will do some work and fetch some data from worker thread and after return it will emit signal "make".

This is code of user class

```
struct my_struct{
   int cur_make_id;
   int cur_send_id;    //there may be many id's if multiple signals
}

void on_send_cb(core, gpointer data){
   my_struct *user_data = (my_struct *) data;
   printf("cure_make_id %d", user_data->cur_make_id);   \\ this prints "4" everytime  
   printf("cure_send_id %d", user_data->cur_send_id);   \\ this prints "2" everytime  
}

void on_make_cb(core, gpointer data){
   my_struct *user_data = (my_struct *) data;
   printf("cure_make_id %d", user_data->cur_make_id);   \\ this prints "4" everytime  
   for(int index=0;index<3;index++){
       call_send();
       user_data->cur_send_id = index;
       g_signal_connect(core, "send", G_CALLBACK(on_send_cb), user_data );
   }     
}

void function(){
   my_struct *user_data = g_malloc0(sizeof(my_struct));
   for(int index=0;index<5;index++){
       call_make();
       user_data->cur_make_id = index;
       g_signal_connect(core, "make", G_CALLBACK(on_make_cb), user_data );
   }
}
```

I get wrong cur_make_id and cur_send_id for all signals (getting last index of for loop)

I know signal_emit and connect delayed and for loop moved forward. I want to know how can I share this user_data to callback so that I can know that this callback is for which index?

(for simplicity I made these `call_make()` api's, I can't change arguments of api's)

Comment: What is `core`? Does this code compiles?

Comment: I have changed this code for simplicity. '`core` is class from where this signal emits. Yes code compiles I get signals as well. I just want to know how to share `user_data`. I can't share full code

Comment: "I get wrong cur_make_id and cur_send_id for all signals (getting last index of for loop)" You know that you only allocate one structure holding one index and use it in your loop, do you? BTW: How and when do you send your signals and when are your callbacks called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only talking about the `user_data` provided during connecting the callback, you have wrong memory allocation:

```
void function(){
   my_struct *user_data = g_malloc0(sizeof(my_struct));
   for(int index=0;index<5;index++){
       call_make();
       user_data->cur_make_id = index;
       g_signal_connect(core, "make", G_CALLBACK(on_make_cb), user_data );
   }
}
```

In this function you have only 1 single block of memory that is passed to all connected callback functions. Whenever the callbacks are called, they will see whatever was written there last. 
In your case this will be `index=4`.

To provide different data for different handlers, you actually need to allocate different data:

```
void function(){
   for(int index=0;index<5;index++){
       my_struct *user_data = g_malloc0(sizeof(my_struct));
       call_make();
       user_data->cur_make_id = index;
       g_signal_connect(core, "make", G_CALLBACK(on_make_cb), user_data);
   }
}
```

If you also have problems providing data from the function triggering the signal, you need to show more code.

Comment: Yes this worked but I have one more query
if I put `g_signal_connect` in for loop then call back function is hit 25 times. (5 times for each index). Where should I put this `g_signal_connect` ?

Comment: Why do you connect 5 times if you only want 1 callback? What is purpose of all that stuff? Without more details how you want to use that its hard to answer.

Comment: For example 
I want to create a context and that context can have 5 networks. so for Context creation I will call `context-create` api and I will get created-context handle through signal.
 Now for that context I need to create all 5 networks so I will call `network-create()` api (with some arguments) for 5 times and I will receive g_signal with every created network handle. So I will need to connect 5 times and context->network[index] will be filled within callback using index.

Comment: Maybe you should not use 1 `core` to connect the handlers but connect to the specific context instead.