# g_signal_connect in loop is good idea?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glib

Ok, so I have a custom GObject to handle network creation, to notify connected handlers I created a signal in the class_init_function (core is singleton object):

```
static void sample_core_class_init (SampleCore *klass)
{
  sample_core_signals[NETWORK_CREATE] = g_signal_new(
    "network-create",
    G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS(klass),
    G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    G_TYPE_NONE,
    1,
    G_TYPE_INT /* Keycode */
  );
}

network_create(){
    int network_handle;
    /* will do some internal work*/
    g_signal_emit(core, sample_core_signals[NETWORK_CREATE], 0, network_handle);
}
```

and g_signal_connect will be written in a loop in different file because I have to create few networks for a single context

```
struct my_struct{
   int cur_network_id;
}

void on_create_cb(core, gpointer data){
   my_struct *user_data = (my_struct *) data;
   printf("cure_network_id %d", user_data->cur_network_id);  // will print 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
}

void function(){
    for(int index=0;index<3;index++){
       my_struct *user_data = g_malloc0(sizeof(my_struct));
       network_create();
       user_data->cur_network_id = index;
       g_signal_connect(core, "make", G_CALLBACK(on_create_cb), user_data );
    }
}
```

g_signal_connect is asynchronous so `function()` will finish first and then call backs will be hit.
In `function()` there will be 3 signal connect -> `g_signal_connect(....,user_data1), g_signal_connect(....,user_data2) and g_signal_connect(....,user_data3)` 
so when there is `g_signal_emit` called then this will connect with all 3 `g_signal_connect` therefore
for this loop of size 3, `on_create_cb` will be hit for 9 times.

How this can be handled accurately? Can `g_signal_connect` be used in a loop?

Comment: it seems you have not actually explained what the problem is that you want handled... There is nothing in the code that explains why you would get 9 signal emissions if that was the issue.

Comment: This is a followup question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082474/how-to-send-user-data-with-gtk-signals-in-loop/62083064#62083064

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment to your previous question, you should not connect all callbacks to the one any only `core` object but to the objects they are related to. I.e. the controller or the network.

Comment: For me it seems as if you (ab)use the `userdata` pointer provided during connecting the handler as an identifier for the object it is related to. You might think about introducing an extra parameter to your callback function. Like the `widget` parameter in moste GTK signal handlers.

Comment: core is singleton class and this signal is emitted from core class so I think these signals will be connected to single core object only. I just want to know have anyone used g_signal_connect in loop?  Can you share any available code related to this?

Comment: `g_signal_connect` is not asynchronous...

Comment: Your problem is not using `g_signal_connect` in a loop but using the same object all the time. If you connect 10 signal handlers for same signal at same object, you will get 10s call per sent signal. How should something different be possible? If you loop over an array of your "network" object and connect only 1 signal handler per object, it will be perfectly fine with a loop.

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your created objects? Maybe we can suggest better solution then. Also showing sending the `make` signal might help